# Accessing an Express API from a Production React app on a hosted server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, apache

I have a Lightsail instance, Ubuntu, and my React application built with Vite. There's a default Apache configuration for the Lightsail Bitnami instance, so for testing I just moved the root directory to that of my `dist/` folder from my Vite production build.

This works, but I also have an Express API running on port 3000 that I can hit while in development, but in prod when I make the request I get a CORS error. I did try doing a reverse proxy in my Apache settings but no luck. I've never used Apache before, only some very little experience with NGINX.

Here's my Express code:

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
//other imports

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(cors({
  origin: "*"
}))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
 // my code that never gets run cause the route never gets hit in production
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started and listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Here's my Apache config

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyPass /test http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:3000/

  DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/my-app/dist"
  <Directory "/home/bitnami/my-app/dist">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf"
```

Here's the relevant React code:

```js
function handleSubmit() {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(
      `/test?start=${start}&end=${end}&id=${Player.playerInfo.videoData.video_id}`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        // doing stuff with response
      })
  }
```

and here's the network response in my production site when I try to hit the route:

[image: Network response]

[image: Route headers]

I know I'm missing some configuration or something obvious, the route definitely shouldn't be trying to access 127.0.0.1 in prod, but I've no experience with deploying code for production, and I'm trying to get the hang of this, but my googling has led to not much.